# Creating a ConcurrentHashMap that supports "snapshots"

Tags: java, multithreading, algorithm, data-structures, snapshot

I'm attempting to create a `ConcurrentHashMap` that supports "snapshots" in order to provide consistent iterators, and am wondering if there's a more efficient way to do this.  The problem is that if two iterators are created at the same time then they need to read the same values, and the definition of the concurrent hash map's weakly consistent iterators does not guarantee this to be the case.  I'd also like to avoid locks if possible: there are several thousand values in the map and processing each item takes several dozen milliseconds, and I don't want to have to block writers during this time as this could result in writers blocking for a minute or longer.

What I have so far:

1. The `ConcurrentHashMap's` keys are Strings, and its values are instances of `ConcurrentSkipListMap<Long, T>`
2. When an element is added to the hashmap with `putIfAbsent`, then a new skiplist is allocated, and the object is added via `skipList.put(System.nanoTime(), t)`.
3. To query the map, I use `map.get(key).lastEntry().getValue()` to return the most recent value.  To query a snapshot (e.g. with an iterator), I use `map.get(key).lowerEntry(iteratorTimestamp).getValue()`, where `iteratorTimestamp` is the result of `System.nanoTime()` called when the iterator was initialized.
4. If an object is deleted, I use `map.get(key).put(timestamp, SnapShotMap.DELETED)`, where DELETED is a static final object.

Questions:

1. Is there a library that already implements this?  Or barring that, is there a data structure that would be more appropriate than the `ConcurrentHashMap` and the `ConcurrentSkipListMap`?  My keys are comparable, so maybe some sort of concurrent tree would better support snapshots than a concurrent hash table.
2. How do I prevent this thing from continually growing?  I can delete all of the skip list entries with keys less than X (except for the last key in the map) after all iterators that were initialized on or before X have completed, but I don't know of a good way to determine when this has happened: I can flag that an iterator has completed when its `hasNext` method returns false, but not all iterators are necessarily going to run to completion; I can keep a `WeakReference` to an iterator so that I can detect when it's been garbage collected, but I can't think of a good way to detect this other than by using a thread that iterates through the collection of weak references and then sleeps for several minutes - ideally the thread would block on the `WeakReference` and be notified when the wrapped reference is GC'd, but I don't think this is an option.

   ```
   ConcurrentSkipListMap<Long, WeakReference<Iterator>> iteratorMap;
   while(true) {
       long latestGC = 0;
       for(Map.Entry<Long, WeakReference<Iterator>> entry : iteratorMap.entrySet()) {
           if(entry.getValue().get() == null) {
               iteratorMap.remove(entry.getKey());
               latestGC = entry.getKey();
           } else break;
       }
       // remove ConcurrentHashMap entries with timestamps less than `latestGC`
       Thread.sleep(300000); // five minutes
   }
   ```

**Edit:** To clear up some confusion in the answers and comments, I'm currently passing weakly consistent iterators to code written by another division in the company, and they have asked me to increase the strength of the iterators' consistency. They are already aware of the fact that it is infeasible for me to make 100% consistent iterators, they just want a best effort on my part. They care more about throughput than iterator consistency, so coarse-grained locks are not an option.

Answer (score 5):

What is your actual use case that requires a special implementation?  From the Javadoc of [ConcurrentHashMap](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentHashMap.html) (emphasis added):

> Retrievals reflect the results of the most recently completed update operations holding upon their onset. ... **Iterators and Enumerations return elements reflecting the state of the hash table at some point at or since the creation of the iterator/enumeration.** They do not throw ConcurrentModificationException. However, iterators are designed to be used by only one thread at a time.

So the regular `ConcurrentHashMap.values().iterator()` will give you a "consistent" iterator, but only for one-time use by a single thread.  If you need to use the same "snapshot" multiple times and/or by multiple threads, I suggest making a copy of the map.

**EDIT:** With the new information and the insistence for a "strongly consistent" iterator, I offer this solution.  Please note that the use of a ReadWriteLock has the following implications:

- *Writes will be serialized* (only one writer at a time) so write performance may be impacted.
- *Concurrent reads are allowed* as long as there is no write in progress, so read performance impact should be minimal.
- Active *readers block writers* but only as long as it takes to retrieve the reference to the current "snapshot".  Once a thread has the snapshot, it no longer blocks writers no matter how long it takes to process the information in the snapshot.
- *Readers are blocked* while any write is active; once the write finishes then all readers will have access to the new snapshot until a new write replaces it.

Consistency is achieved by serializing the writes and making a *copy* of the current values on *each and every write*.  Readers that hold a reference to a "stale" snapshot can continue to use the old snapshot without worrying about modification, and the garbage collector will reclaim old snapshots as soon as no one is using it any more.  It is assumed that there is *no requirement* for a reader to request a snapshot from an earlier point in time.

Because snapshots are potentially shared among multiple concurrent threads, the snapshots are read-only and cannot be modified.  This restriction also applies to the `remove()` method of any `Iterator` instances created from the snapshot.

```
import java.util.*;
import java.util.concurrent.locks.*;

public class StackOverflow16600019 <K, V> {
    private final ReadWriteLock locks = new ReentrantReadWriteLock();
    private final HashMap<K,V> map = new HashMap<>();
    private Collection<V> valueSnapshot = Collections.emptyList();

    public V put(K key, V value) {
        locks.writeLock().lock();
        try {
            V oldValue = map.put(key, value);
            updateSnapshot();
            return oldValue;
        } finally {
            locks.writeLock().unlock();
        }
    }

    public V remove(K key) {
        locks.writeLock().lock();
        try {
            V removed = map.remove(key);
            updateSnapshot();
            return removed;
        } finally {
            locks.writeLock().unlock();
        }
    }

    public Collection<V> values() {
        locks.readLock().lock();
        try {
            return valueSnapshot; // read-only!
        } finally {
            locks.readLock().unlock();
        }
    }

    /** Callers MUST hold the WRITE LOCK. */
    private void updateSnapshot() {
        valueSnapshot = Collections.unmodifiableCollection(
            new ArrayList<V>(map.values())); // copy
    }
}
```

Comment: I need the iterator to reflect the state of the map **at** the time of the iterator's creation, not **at or since** the time of the iterator's creation.  Also from the Javadoc: "The view's iterator is a "weakly consistent" iterator that ... traverses elements as they existed upon construction of the iterator, and may (but is not guaranteed to) reflect any modifications subsequent to construction;" I need an iterator that does not reflect any changes made to the map subsequent to the iterator's creation

Comment: The timing of executions within highly concurrent threads, in many cases, makes the described "weak" consistency _good enough_ for most needs that simply need a stable snapshot of what _was_ at some point (even now) with the understanding that at _any_ point that snapshot is likely out of date.  But, if you *really* need such strong consistency, then more information is necessary.  [edit: I don't see a need for any WeakReferences]  One option is wrapping the map and controlling via a ReentrantReadWriteLock if concurrent reads are much more frequent than writes.

Comment: +1 in concurrent use cases, one must be clear about what exactly makes the state of the map *incorrect* one microsecond later, in this case, after creating the iterator. You could use a ReradWriteLock and aquire the readlock before iterating. Or use a Copy-On-Write collection, which supports shnapshots.

Comment: From the edited question: _The problem is that if two iterators are created at the same time then they need to read the same values..._

The assumption is that two iterators are created at exactly the same time.  No single thread can create two iterators at the same time.  When you have multiple threads it is technically possible, but _how do you know_ that the two threads attempted to create an iterator at "exactly" the same time?  Even if two threads request it at the exact same microsecond, the OS/JVM could schedule a 3rd thread to modify the data after the 1st iterator but before the 2nd.

Comment: @William Price I'm not assuming that two iterators were created at exactly the same time, and neither is the client.  If the client occasionally sees that two iterators that were created at the "same time" return different elements then they're smart enough to realize that this was caused by any number of delays in the system; however, this is happening all of the time with `ConcurrentHashMap's` weakly consistent iterators, and so they've asked me to provide iterators that have stronger consistency guarantees.

Comment: You've stated that your clients "_care more about throughput than iterator consistency_" but you insist that you need more consistency than provided by ConcurrentHashMap.  So please tell us more about the runtime environment (e.g. frequency and number of reader threads, frequency and number of writer threads) and under what conditions, exactly, two iterators retrieved by different threads in rapid succession are "allowed" to give different results.  Without this, I have to assume that writer threads are changing the data _all the time_ and it's unlikely that any two iterators will match.

Comment: When I said "two iterators created at the same time should produce the same results," I ought to have said "an iterator should reflect the state of the map at the time of its creation," which implies that two iterators created at the same time should produce the same results, but which also implies that two iterators created at different times. where only one update occurred in the intervening time, should produce the same results *except* for the element that was updated.  The persistent map I described in my question solves this problem except that it consumes a lot of memory, and I was

Comment: looking for a better way to clean up the map than with the weak hash map queue I'd implemented.

Comment: Zim-Zam, you are keeping all of your requirements to yourself and then using them to reject the help that is offered you.  After multiple requests, you have yet to tell us about the characteristics of the system and, now, whatever "clean up" requirements you have in mind.  We cannot give you anything "better" because no one knows how to measure "better" unless you communicate ALL assumptions, requirements, and constraints to us.  I wish you luck, but I can't read your mind.

Answer (score 4):

I've found that the [ctrie](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ctrie) is the ideal solution - it's a concurrent hash array mapped trie with constant time snapshots

Answer (score 0):

Solution1) What about just synchronizing on the puts, and on the iteration.  That should give you a consistent snapshot.

Solution2) Start iterating and make a boolean to say so, then override the puts, putAll so that they go into a queue, when the iteration is finished simply make those puts with the changed values.

Comment: That would be fine in a non-concurrent environment, but in this case the locks would kill the map's throughput - I'd rather use extra memory and maintain a high degree of concurrency than minimize memory and settle for single-threaded performance