# Java: get-snapshot and listen-to-updates enabled datastructure

Tags: java, multithreading, data-structures

I am looking for datastructure which enables following operations upon it:

- feed(Object key, Object value)
- getSnapshot(UpdateListener u): Map[Key, Value]

which allows to feed data into it and retrieve data in async manner.

**Usage example:** organizing task pool, when task execution is triggered by some event. When execution is triggered, task executor takes a snapshot and starts executing tasks in it. Upon receiving new tasks, task executor does them as well.

Comment: Ctrie was the answer for a similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16600019/creating-a-concurrenthashmap-that-supports-snapshots