# What is a efficient way of storing snapshots of an in-memory key-value store in Java?

Tags: hashmap, snapshot, key-value-store

I am trying to design an in-memory key-value store that maps strings to strings of variable length. I also want to give it the ability to take snapshots of its key-value data sets for any particular moment in time. Moreover, modifications to the key-value store should not affect past snapshots. I am currently using a HashMap for this, and for snapshots I maintain a mapping of timestamps to deep-copies of the respective HashMap's entry sets (with simple String compression). Are there any other more effective methods of doing this in-memory?

I am wondering, is it perhaps more memory-efficient, since I am working with strings of characters, to use tries instead?

Comment: Another possibility is an event-sourced approach - store a log of all *changes* to the hashmap.  If the number of changes between snapshots are a small proportion of the overall size, this may be a lot more efficient.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Interesting.  A little research shows that a Ctrie might be what you are looking for.  Wiki:  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ctrie

ctrie:  Concurrent Tries with Efficient Non-Blocking Snapshots

Looks like there is code available in multiple languages 
 java haskell python C++

Found related :
[Creating a ConcurrentHashMap that supports "snapshots"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16600019/creating-a-concurrenthashmap-that-supports-snapshots)

and searching Stackoverflow:  https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=ctrie