# How to make an immutable copy of a `ConcurrentHashMap`?

Tags: java, java.util.concurrent

[ConcurrentHashMap](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentHashMap.html) is useful also in Scala for handling state in a thread safe manner.

I'd like to make an immutable snapshot of it, for local processing. Is there a simple way to do this?

---

Clarification: having things change while making the snapshot is okay. I just need some shot in time that will then be used (the immutable use) for 2-3 seconds, and discarded.

Interim status: Thanks for all the ideas, that was fast! :) I'll check them out but it seems just Scala maps and a `synchronized` might be the path of least complexity, for me.

Comment: You can use [`Collections.unmodifiableMap`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#unmodifiableMap(java.util.Map)) to wrap it.

Comment: You might want to check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16600019/creating-a-concurrenthashmap-that-supports-snapshots

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Creating a ConcurrentHashMap that supports "snapshots"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16600019/creating-a-concurrenthashmap-that-supports-snapshots)

Comment: One thing is that most of the concurrent classes are "weakly consistent" meaning there's no way to prevent modification as you iterate through them (for any reason, but including say making a copy).  If you want some sort of master lock on a concurrent data structure so you can bypass the weakly consistent property I think you're no longer in the realm of "simple."

Answer (score 0):

Well, you could use [Guava's ImmutableMap](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/23.0/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/ImmutableMap.html):

```
ImmutableMap<K, V> immutableCopy = ImmutableMap.copyOf(yourConcurrentMap);
```

Of course if there happen to be writes during the copy operation those might end up in the copy as well.

Comment: Thanks. Changes during the creation of the snapshot are okay for me. Since Scala is my platform, I will likely not reach all the way to Guava.

Comment: @akauppi I'm not that familiar with Scala but you should be able to directly use Guava from your Scala code.